# Not have Subquery,But the mysql throw Subquery return more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

A standard insert MySQL query without any Subquery, but the MySQL tells me

> Subquery return more than 1 row

```
 INSERT INTO 
    db_novelV2.tbl_saler_todo
(   
    is_drive, customer_type, operator_id, STATUS, remark, 
    update_dt, receive_saler, src_id, come_dt, has_give_present, 
    TYPE, service_id, src_type, allot_saler, has_car_shuttle, 
    customer_id, session_id, arrive_dt, creater_id, leave_dt, 
    collector_id, store_id, allot_dt, add_dt
) 
VALUES 
(0, 0, 528, 0, '',NULL, 307,0, NOW(), 0, 1, 352,0,307, 0, 243465,2993333,NOW(), 528, NULL, 0,4, NOW(), NOW());
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have any INSERT triggers on your table, If so, disable any triggers before running your INSERT statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have **rebuild** the index, and the insert MySQL query have worked normally.May be the table index had broken at recently.